# GCM messaging. What could be 3rd party server?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to implement a simple service based on GCM. Google platform requires 3rd app party server to communicate with GCM cloud (see: [GCM architecture](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)).  My question is: is it possible to use some of Google cloud components as 3rd party server?

Comment: I am currently facing the same problem. I'm writing an App where a Server needs to notify the App. (GCM is the the best way, isn't it?) My Plan is to use GCM for Server->Device communicaion and Endpoints for Device->Server Communication. So I'm thinkging about to use the AppEngine where I implemented the Endpoints to use as a 3rd party server to communicate with GCM.  So, is this possible or do you already have a different solution (since this questiion is quite old now...)

Comment: @0xAffe I have implemented pure GAE solution. So, I have an android devices with installed app used to register them to GCM.  When app is started first time it registers device to GCM and gets device id, that is next stored in cloud datastore by hitting GAE servlet. Another GAE servlet is used to communicate back to already registered devices.

Comment: I think I now did it nearly the same way like @JAW.  I used a Python GCM Library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-gcm)  in my Endpoints module. Now I can get the registration IDs from my cloud Datastore and send notifications to the user.

Answer (score 2):

GCM does not provide you with something you can use a server, though you can use Google App Engine.

Comment: Thanks. Have you seen an use case of GAE as 3rd party server? I just start from scratch. BTW, I'm still waiting to be trial partner to use upstream messaging and user notifications via CCS. Why it is not automatic decision?

Answer (score 1):

A 3rd party server can be any web server that can do the following :

1. Implements an API call that receives registration IDs from devices that installed your application, and persists them in a database.
2. Can send HTTP requests to Google Cloud Messaging endpoint, in order to send GCM messages to your application.

Beyond these things, it should implement whatever logic determines when and what GCM messages are delivered to the users of your application.